# How to swipe from last to first tab in TabBarView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, tabbar, pageviews

Can someone tell me if it's there is a way to make a TabBarView or PageView to swipe to initialIndex/initialPage or last one if the current view is the initial one?

I couldn't find a method to do it.

Comment: Actually with the swipe action, or have a button that will send you to the last page?

Comment: @JoãoSoares with the swipe action. Already have implemented with buttons but was looking for a way to use a swipe action.

Comment: How would you intend to differentiate between just swiping to the next page and swiping to the last one?

Comment: @JoãoSoares I managed to solve it using PageView, you can check my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it with PageView and setting the initial page to a bigger number and not setting itemCount.

```
    int _curentPage = 0;
    final initialPage = 98;

    @override
      void initState() {
        pageController = PageController(initialPage: initialPage);
        super.initState();
      }

@override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: PageView.builder(
                controller: pageController,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return eventPages[(eventPages.length - (initialPage - index - 1) % eventPages.length - 1)];
                },
                onPageChanged: (pageNum) {
                  _curentPage = (eventPages.length - (initialPage - pageNum - 1) % eventPages.length - 1);
                  _updateBottomBar();
                },
            )
        );
      }
```